# MAC address Iphone and Desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery mobile. I want to get the MAC Address of the device, my Iphone app is used on.. It could be used on computer too. So basically I want a script which is cross browser and should support multiple devices too..  I tried searching on internet but couldn't find a solution. Can anyone tell that is it even possible? If yes, then an example code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ian I have to make it cross platform, i.e. just not from Iphone but other devices too.. could be an android or desktop or ipad.. so this solution won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

NO, it is impossible, JavaScript does not provide access to MAC adress and even on server side you can not get it except if the client is on the same ethernet segment as the server.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "How to get MAC address" using Javascript then the answer is "No way".
There is a way to do it in IE, but since you mentioned iPhone I guess its not an option.